# Count/Sum Distinct in Google Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have physical and injury data and I'm looking to show the amount of days missed for each injury. I have an Injury Column that shows the region of injury (Knee, Ankle, Foot, etc), a Diagnosis Column (MCL Sprain, Ankle Tear, Foot Fracture, etc) and a Time Missed (Days) Column. However I want to show the number of days missed for each specific injury in a bar chart on ***Google Studio***. For example Player 1 Missed 29 days because of a Knee Injury, however, later on in the year he suffered another Knee Injury but this time only missed 10 days. At the moment ***Google Studio*** sums the two so the bar chart shows that he missed 39 days due to a Knee Injury. Count Distinct did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Count Distinct` is for counting distinct data.

You have 2 dimensions (Play Name and Region of Injury) and 1 date range (Year).

You need to set:

1. breakdown dimension, the default aggregation would sum for you
2. a [controll](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144?hl=en)

To summarize:

- Dimension: Player Name
- Breakdown Dimension: Region of Injury, Year
- Metric: Time Missed
- Control: Drop-down list, or Date range control with Year to be the control field

Comment: I currently have all those things except it won't let me add a second dimension to the breakdown dimension. I have the default date range set to custom "This year to date"

Comment: Bar chart is not for 3 or more dimensions. Should upu consider using pivot table?

Comment: Going to have to create Unique Injury IDs in order for this to work. I believe you can do this using a script but I only want the IDs to generate if the Injury Column cell has a value. If its blank I want the Injury ID column cell to be blank

Comment: Please create a new question and provide more information about the (format of) ID you want.